# open files using file paths in c

Tags: c, directory, fopen, filepath

i have a file containing list paths and other related information of all the files in a directory and sub directories. its partial content is as given at the end.
My problem is:

i tried to read this file and open all the files in the list as follows. None of them have successes in opening.

the partial code:
I used `strtok()` to cut out the other parts of the files information

```
char *token=NULL;
unsigned long file_size;
char file_fp[33];
char file_path[150];
char fname_buffer[1024];
char file_list[32];
std::cout<<"Enter file name containing the file list\n";
std::cin>>file_list;
FILE *flist=fopen(file_list,"r+b");
if(!flist)
{
    std::cout<<"Could not open "<<file_list<<
     " for reading\n Please rerun the program and enter the correct file name.";
    return(1);
}
else while(fgets(fname_buffer,1024,flist))
{
   // if ('\n' != fname_buffer[0])
        token = strtok( fname_buffer," ,\t");
    file_size=atol(token);
    
  //  if ('\n' != fname_buffer[0])
        token = strtok(NULL, " ,\t"); 
    strncpy((char*)file_fp,token,32);

   // if ('\n' != fname_buffer[0])
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    strcpy(file_path,token);
     
    FILE *input_file=fopen(file_path, "r+b");
    
    if(input_file == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "Could not open file %s for reading, error code %d!\n",
                token,
                errno);
        continue;
    }
```

**........**

partial file_list file content:

> 1883408  5291b5e9c117677f34fe39ac72983eba  E:\papers(Ãâ·Ñ)ºSOA+with+.NET+and+Windows+Azure00018.pdf
>
> 474231  a6f96231c62bd457c5f06201553a468f  E:\papers\06_un_ict_task_force_african_development_status.pdf
>
> 298547  4ba159f5b1123a89c118bb5814af13f9  E:\papers\10.1.1.119.6128.pdf
>
> 1639991  a60672ae9f88c0c1ab2d33bac68572c6  E:\papers\20100602_roger_mcilmoyle_sungard.pdf
>
> 501015  0d6a4cace5815c82a2627e52bb5ae6e9  E:\papers\a case for cloud storage diversity.pdf

And more:

How can I remove the file extensions from these file paths in order to use them as a file name

EDIT:
The error i get is

> error code 2, File or directory could not be found

EDIT:

this is the actual output I get

> Enter file name containing the file list fileinfo.txt
>
> Could not open
> file E:\papers(├â├ó┬╖├æ)┬ú┬║SOA+with+.NET+and+Windows+Azure00018 .pdf
> for reading, error code 22!
>
> Could not open file
> E:\papers\06_un_ict_task_force_african_development_status.pdf  for
> reading, error code 22!

EDIT:
VC2010 required to use  double slash in place of the single slashes for the directory traversals

Comment: What error do you get from `fopen`? Is the file name correct?

Comment: What is the path of the file displayed in the `fprintf()` statement in the `if(input_file == NULL)` branch?

Comment: How about the filename (the `token`/`file_path` variables), is it extracted correctly?

Comment: @hmjd: please look at the last edit

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: i did some corrections to the tokenizer and now i am sure the variables match. But i still have the same problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing all of this on Windows, and your text file (`file_list`) has windows line endings, then strtok is not able to split the lines in the file (Windows line ending is: \r\n): so strtok will give you **file_path\r**.

Solution: read your file list file in text mode: `FILE *flist=fopen(file_list,"r+t")`

I would advice also:

1. Make your `file_path` longer (at least 256)
2. Check what `strtok` returns (it can return **NULL** if one of the lines in your file does not have enough tokens and then you're tosted :))

Comment: try: `FILE *input_file=fopen(file_path, "rb")`

Comment: I have just compiled and run your program: the `fgets` function may return newline character in your `file_path` buffer (e.g.: `E:\\papers\\06_un_ict_task_force_african_development_status.pdf\\n`. Get rid of that newline before calling `fopen`.

Comment: size_t n = strlen(file_path); if(file_path[n] == '\n') file_path[n] = '\0';

Comment: this also couldn't solve it. In the debug mode and in the output i can see that there is(are) spaces at the beginning of the file name. How can i get rid of them?

Comment: @John - Create a pointer and point it at the first character of your file name.  Then, a loop like `while (*ptr == ' ') ptr++;` should advance the pointer to the first non-space character.  At that point, use `ptr` as the pointer to the filename instead of `file_path`.